# What is the mechanical size of a horse with a cart?

Tags: dnd-5e, creature-size, mount

A riding horse on its own is considered Large in game terms (20 square feet). When it's drawing a cart, what size is it considered to be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Carts are Large objects**, per the table of sample object sizes on p. 247 of the DMG.

So a horse with a cart is a **Large creature pulling a Large object**, occupying a **10' wide x 20' long** area.

Note that this isn't treated as a single creature, since creatures can squeeze to move through spaces one size smaller than themselves. Objects, including carts, cannot squeeze.

There are no specific rules for how a horse and cart can move (in terms of actions, speed, or limits to turning). D&D 5e generally prefers to leave details like that up to the DM.

Comment: But if it occupies a space of 10 x 20 feet  how do you spin it around every direction becouse it's not a square it's harder to make it move in any direction?

Comment: @Spellcaster that's kinda the point, isn't it? You can't rotate a real-life horse & cart in place either.

Comment: @Spellcaster There are no rules for that. Running combat on a grid is itself an optional rule. D&D 5e isn't a tactical miniatures wargame, and by design doesn't provide specific rules for every possible circumstance.